# how to have publishing, blog and wiki features together?

Tags: publishing-site, wiki, blog

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008.

I want to have blog and wiki features as well as publishing portal features. Any ideas how to integrate publishing portal, blog and wiki?

by integrate, I mean using the same user name and password to pass through authentication of publishing portal, blog and wiki. And should I setup 3 different site collections for publishing portal, blog and wiki (I find if I setup publishing portal site collection, I can not create blog and wiki sub-site)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create sub-sites for your publishing portal that are not publishing sites using the stsadm command: stsadm.exe -o createweb -url http://path-to-publishing-site/subsite-name -sitetemplate  -title

For more information, see here: http://sharepointhillbilly.com/archive/2009/07/09/creating-a-sub-site-of-a-publishing-site-that-is-not.aspx.

Comment: Cool, question answered!